# [h || rich]:dataTable not iterating over all objects

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, richfaces

I have a java backing bean which has a method (call it `getDataList()`) which returns an `ArrayList<MyType>`.

In `MyType.java` I have a load of setters and getters all of which either assign `String`s or `String[]`s.
An example instantiation assigns 4 objects to the ArrayList, containing (among other) the following data:

```
fid = 1    ftid = 1
fid = 2    ftid = 1
fid = 3    ftid = 1
fid = 3    ftid = 2
```

In my jsf code I'm referencing the structure into a rich:dataTable.  Trouble is the table comes out like this:

```
fid        ftid
1          1
2          1
3          2      # should be 3, 1
3          2
```

As you can see the last-but-one iteration is incorrect.  i've tried this with a h:dataTable and the same happens so I know it's probably not richfaces.  but my java console through eclipse(ganymede/tomcat6) shows the correct assignment:

```
|STDOUT| 2010-02-08 15:23:58,953 | INFO  | [http-8989-5]: adding ftqId 1 feedId 1
|STDOUT| 2010-02-08 15:23:58,984 | INFO  | [http-8989-5]: adding ftqId 1 feedId 2
|STDOUT| 2010-02-08 15:23:59,000 | INFO  | [http-8989-5]: adding ftqId 1 feedId 3
|STDOUT| 2010-02-08 15:23:59,000 | INFO  | [http-8989-5]: adding ftqId 2 feedId 3
```

can anyone tell me how to extract the data from my ArrayList object correctly?  Should I use a hashmap?

As per request here are the smallest snippets of relevant code (thanks Colin):

This is the bean code:

```
public ArrayList<MyType> getFDataList() {
    XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler();
    dataList = new ArrayList<MyType>();
    try {Document doc = handler.XMLDoc("Config.xml");} // catches removed
    String[] fIds = handler.XMLList("//snip/fid/text()");
    for (String fId : fIds) {           
        MyType tld = new MyType();
        String[] ftIds = handler.XMLList("//snip/ftid/text()");
        for (String ftId : ftIds) {
            tld.setFtId(ftId);
            tld.setFId(fId);        
            logger.info("ftId:"+ftId+",fId:"+fId);
            dataList.add(tld);  // each ft
        }
    }
    return dataList;
}
```

This is the supporting class code:

```
public class MyType {
    private String fId;
    private String ftId;

    public String getFId() {  
        return fId;  
    }  

    public void setFId(String f) {  
        fId = f;  
    } 

    public String getFtId() {  
        return ftId;  
    }  

    public void setFtId(String fi) {  
        ftId = fi;  
    } 
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that I'm nesting the work done which adds the object to the ArrayList, but I don't think that should matter.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of explaining your code, just give it.

Comment: how do i do that when i have 600 chars of a comment to list it?

Comment: There's no such bug in `UIData`, so the way how you populate or access the list must be wrong. Please post an SSCCE http://sscce.org (i.e. get rid of all irrelevant/unrelated code clutter until you get the smallest possible snippet which reproduces exactly the problem).

Comment: how can i put code in a comment so that it reads as `code` (which i've noticed doesn't work)?  when i search for code and comments i obviously get posts about commenting one's code...

Comment: You can make an edit to your question to add the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be creating a new `MyType` object each time in the inner loop. What is happening is that you are only creating one instance of the object for each `fId`, but for each `ftId` you are overwriting the value and adding it to the list. You end up with multiple references to the same object.

Move the instantiation inside the inner loop like this.

```
   for (String fId : fIds) {         
        String[] ftIds = handler.XMLList("//snip/ftid/text()");
        for (String ftId : ftIds) {  
            MyType tld = new MyType();
            tld.setFtId(ftId);
            tld.setFId(fId);        
            logger.info("ftId:"+ftId+",fId:"+fId);
            dataList.add(tld);  // each ft
        }
    }
```